# Cancel GCD async task when navigating back

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uinavigationcontroller, block, grand-central-dispatch

I have a relatively long running task (5-10 secs) in a view controller in my iOS app. It is running async in the background by GCD. The user has the ability to make UI operations during this task, so he also has the ability to press back button to navigate to the previous view.

My code is pretty straightforward:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.x.y.z", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    TestObject* test = [self getTestObject];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        test.resultset.count > 0 ? 
             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"xy" sender:self] :
             [UIUtils showSimpleAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"NoDataForInterval",nil) 
                             delegate:self];
    });
});
```

Exception info: Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSGenericException`, reason:

> Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'xy'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.

So, the problem is, when my user goes back to the previous view, the task in GCD continues, and when finishing, it crashes my app, because can not perform my segue.

So, my question: how can I cancel my asny task in GCD when navigating to another view? Or just simply test somehow the current view when completing, like

```
if(!self.navigationController)
    return;
```

Or...?

Thanks for all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suspending GCD query problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737044/suspending-gcd-query-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!self.navigationController)
    return;
```

So did you try that? Once you're back on the main thread, it's perfectly safe and reasonable to look around at the state of the interface.

If, on the other hand, you really want to make it easy to cancel your lengthy task in the middle, use NSOperation instead of GCD blocks. This gives you a thread-safe cancellation API.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but I thought it was an ugly solution and there is a better one.

Comment: I don't see why it's ugly, but as I already said, if you really want cancellation in the middle, NSOperation is the way to go. You just need to keep checking periodically for `isCancelled` during your operation and bail out if so. It is thread-safe to cancel on the main thread even though the operation (and `isCancelled`) are happening in the background.