# Stop Dispatchqueue using NotificationCenter in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, dispatch-async

I have some task which I want to do asynchronously. So I am creating dispatchqueue in one class and doing some task.

```
//Adding Observer      
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil, queue: nil, using:catchNotification).
```

.

```
//Creating Background Thread.
     let anotherQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Thread1", qos: .background)

    //Asynch thread.
    anotherQueue.async {
        for i in 0..<50 {
       print("\n ",i)
            sleep(1)
        }
    }
```

but upon some events I want to stop this, and am handling something like this.

```
func catchNotification (notification:Notification) -> Void {
    //Stop the queue.
    anotherQueue.suspend()
}
```

Am posting notification some other class. notification is getting received. but thread is not getting suspended.

Here is the complete class if you want to refer.

LoginPresenter.swift

```
let anotherQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Thread1", qos: .background)
class LoginPresenter : LoginInteractor {
func catchNotification (notification:Notification) -> Void {
    //Stop the queue.
    anotherQueue.suspend()
}

func LoginSuccessFull()
{   
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil, queue: nil, using:catchNotification)

    //Asynch thread.
    anotherQueue.async {
        //Synch
        for i in 0..<50 {
       print("\n ",i)
            sleep(1)
        }
    }
}
```

or is any other better method or mechanism is there to do this ?

Comment: Instead of this, you can show the user with ActivityView on the login screen and then once you get the catch notification stop it and dismiss the viewController.

Comment: The suspension occurs after completion of any blocks running at the time of the call. This is what written in https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchobject/1452801-suspend.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [Apple`s GCD documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch), you could see the following:

> The suspension occurs after completion of any blocks running at the time of the call.

This means that, every block will be executed, what has already been started. Just create a second block in your `LoginSuccessFull` function like:

```
anotherQueue.async {
  print("this is the second block")
}
```

If you suspend straight after the function call, this block will not be executed.

If you would like to `cancel` immediately the operations in `GCD`, you will have to write you own implementation. But to [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737044/suspending-gcd-query-problem/6737719#6737719), it is always the one question for `GCD`, because it is just not [designed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550658/dispatch-queues-how-to-tell-if-theyre-running-and-how-to-stop-them) that way.

The other option would be to use `NSOperationQueue`, but there you have implement right the `cancel` logic for your `NSOperation` subclasses.